# Is it possible to control for a confounding variable in linear mixed models?

Tags: mixed-model, predictor

Is it possible to control for a confounding variable in linear mixed models?

SPSS has a covariate box but I think that is not the same as adding a confounding variable?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is the same thing. That is, covariate = c0ntrol variable.

I don't know what SPSS does (and software questions are off topic here) but covariate is control variable in general statistical terminology.